# Cannot configure my SecurityConfig class without deprecated WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-security

I have added BCryptPasswordEncoder to my project and I store every user's password in my DB in encoded way. And now I can't log in using not encoded password but if I use encoded password I still can log in. As I know, AuthenticationManager have to encode entered password according to bean PasswordEncoder and compare with each password in my DB.

So the question is: why AuthenticationManager doesn't encode entered password?

P.S: As I know, `authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager()` replaces `authenticationConfiguration.userDetailsService(personDetailsService).passwordEncoder(getPasswordEncoder())` since Spring Security 5.7.0-M2.

My SecurityConfig class:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    private final PersonDetailsService personDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(PersonDetailsService personDetailsService) {
        this.personDetailsService = personDetailsService;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/auth/login", "/error", "/auth/registration").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/auth/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/process_login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/hello", true)
                .failureUrl("/auth/login?error")
                .and()
                .logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/auth/login");

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

My RegistrationService:

```
@Service
public class RegistrationService {
    private final PeopleRepository peopleRepository;

    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public RegistrationService(PeopleRepository peopleRepository, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.peopleRepository = peopleRepository;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void register(Person person) {
        person.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(person.getPassword()));
        peopleRepository.save(person);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

If I extend my SecurityConfig from deprecated WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and change my code to this:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final PersonDetailsService personDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(PersonDetailsService personDetailsService) {
        this.personDetailsService = personDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/auth/login", "/error", "/auth/registration").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/auth/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/process_login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/hello", true)
                .failureUrl("/auth/login?error")
                .and()
                .logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/auth/login");

    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(personDetailsService).passwordEncoder(getPasswordEncoder());
    }
}
```

then it works like it have to (entered by user password is getting encrypted by `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` and then it compares to other passwords from DB and if there is the same password found user is authenticated).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Do you really need the `AuthenticationManager` Bean? Have you tried to remove it?

Comment: @MarcusHertdaCoregio I have tried to remove this bean but it didn't help at all.

Comment: What your `/process_login` looks like?

Comment: @MarcusHertdaCoregio /process_login is automatically created by Spring Security. It is just URL to which I should make POST request from my login.html page and which will automatically perform login.